# Finding the Lower Bound (Ω), Upper Bound (O), and Average (Θ) of a Function f(n), given g(n)

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity, analysis-of-algorithms

Let $f(n) = (n + log_2(a))^b$ and $g(n) = n^b$, for any real constants $a$ and $b$, where $b > 0$

a) Using definition of $Ω$ and $g(n)$, establish the lower bound of $f(n)$. Find the values of positive constant $c$ and non-negative integer $n_0$.

b) Using definition of $O$ and $g(n)$, establish the upper bound of $f(n)$. Find the values of positive constant $c$ and non-negative integer $n_0$.

c) Using Θ, what is your conclusion for the relationship between $f(n)$ and $g(n)$?
Prove or disprove your conclusion.

I can't seem to find an example of problem of this type. Does anyone know the best method for solving it? Or does anyone know of any links to relevant examples? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's different if you're on a mobile device, but on a computer, in the little column on the right of the page, there's a section called "Related". There I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1640998/). Together with its multiple answers, they look like great examples/explanations to get you started.

Comment: I'm not finding anything that is helping me understand how to solve this type of problem. A lot of the ones on this website are proofs. Do you know of a method to use for this specific problem?

Comment: Did you read the comments below the accepted answer? David K literally walks the OP through the process.